# connect to BMC Bladelogic Configuration manager using java

Tags: java

i would like to make a connection to Bladelogic configuration manager thru Java to fetch the logs inside it. Since accessing it and fetching the logs taking lot of time and my pc gets hanged sometimes so i wanted to automate this effort without really be logged into bladelogic.

Is this possible ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: i was trying to establishing a connection to bladelogic configuration manager using java. is there any jar file i should use to connect it? Accessing logs inside bladelogic is quite tideous so wanted automate this effort .

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the logs via Java directly is not supported, and having seen previous attempts I would expect that you'll struggle.  However, have you considered using Jython?  This interfaces closely with the underlying Java objects and is fully supported by BMC.  I've personally found this approach to be perfectly adequate for the majority of my requirements.